# How would I rotate an SVG?

Tags: svg

The 1st image is my code now. My question is, if I wanted to rotate the the whole thing so it looks like the below image, what code would I add to it?

https://jsfiddle.net/jw1euh11/

**What it looks like now.**

[image]

**I want to Rotate it to This**

[image]

```html
<svg width="266" height="266" viewBox="0 0 266 266">

  <text x="100" y="15" fill="red" transform="rotate(44, 10,40)">Play </text>
  <text x="197" y="15" fill="red" transform="rotate(44, 10,40)">Play </text>

 <line x1="264" y1="1" x2="0" y2="1"
    style="stroke: #0059dd; stroke-width: 3;"/>

  <line x1="265" y1="265" x2="265" y2="0"
    style="stroke: #0059dd;stroke-width: 3; "/>

 <line x1="100%" y1="265" x2="0" y2="265"
    style="stroke: #0059dd ; stroke-width: 3;"/>

  <line x1="1" y1="100%" x2="1" y2="0"
    style="stroke:#0059dd;stroke-width: 3; "/>

  <line x1="0" y1="0" x2="100%" y2="100%" 
style="stroke:#0059dd; stroke-width:3" />

  <line x1="0" y1="100%" x2="100%" y2="0"
style="stroke:#0059dd; stroke-width:3"/>

</svg>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use group `<g>...</g>` to rotate all together.

```html
<svg width="266" height="266" viewBox="0 0 266 266">
<g transform="rotate(-44, 80, 120)">

  <text x="100" y="15" fill="red" transform="rotate(44, 10,40)">Play </text>
  <text x="197" y="15" fill="red" transform="rotate(44, 10,40)">Play </text>

 <line x1="264" y1="1" x2="0" y2="1"
    style="stroke: #0059dd; stroke-width: 3;"/>

  <line x1="265" y1="265" x2="265" y2="0"
    style="stroke: #0059dd;stroke-width: 3; "/>

 <line x1="100%" y1="265" x2="0" y2="265"
    style="stroke: #0059dd ; stroke-width: 3;"/>

  <line x1="1" y1="100%" x2="1" y2="0"
    style="stroke:#0059dd;stroke-width: 3; "/>

  <line x1="0" y1="0" x2="100%" y2="100%" 
style="stroke:#0059dd; stroke-width:3" />

  <line x1="0" y1="100%" x2="100%" y2="0"
style="stroke:#0059dd; stroke-width:3"/>
</g>
</svg>
```

Comment: How would I view the whole box in its entirety? So the whole thing is view able.

Comment: Well, one way is to rotate whole svg instead of adding group: <svg width="266" height="266" viewBox="0 0 266 266" transform="rotate(-44 0 0) translate(0 70)" > and another is to scale down the group by about square root of 2 scale(0.7) and then translate(dx dy) it to centre but that would result in a smaller size svg, lastly you can do both - scale group down scale(0.71) and scale svg up scale(1.41) and translate one or the other to centre...

Comment: How would I add: transform="rotate(-44 0 0) translate(0 80)" To this code? https://jsfiddle.net/tka8go34/1/

Comment: You wouldn't be able to transform the svg (well, you might be able to, but your red border isn't part of svg, so it wouldn't rotate), so instead you can rotate the div as such: https://jsfiddle.net/msk4h0e5/2/

Comment: I did it this way: transform: rotate(-44deg) translate(0px,80px);
https://jsfiddle.net/w7jajka3/

Comment: 1 other question, How would I make the background black allowing the lines to still be showing? http://jsfiddle.net/wb5fwLoc/3/ It uses linear-gradient to display a line by setting other parts invisible, you can change the color by modifying the visible parts with alpha channel = 1. I keep trying and when I do it, only one line is left showing.

Comment: Yep, that's pretty much the same. Other lines are just for compatibility with various versions of different browsers.

Comment: Can you answer the question about how to make the background black. I've been trying to do that. CSS version: http://jsfiddle.net/wb5fwLoc/3/